# Docker - How to access a volume not attached to a container?

Tags: docker, containers, data-containers, docker-volume

I have (had) a data container which has a volume used by other containers (--volumes-from).

The data container has accidentally been removed.

Thankfully the volume was not removed.

Is there any way I can re run the data container and point it BACK to this volume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way can re run the data container and point it BACK to this volume?

Sure, I detailed it in "[How to recover data from a deleted Docker container? How to reconnect it to the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33164156/6309)"

You need to create a new container with the same VOLUME (but **[its path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31997267/6309)** `/var/lib/docker/volumes/...` would be empty or with an initial content)

Then you move your legacy volume to the path of the volume of the new container.

More generally, whenever I start a data volume container, [I register its volume path in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32113001/6309) (to reuse that path later if my container is accidentally removed)

Comment: You are a star, sounds like the perfect solution.  My only issue now is to try to work out which of the 50 volumes on that machine is the one that i need!!      Once that is done Ill use your approach for keeping track of the volume in use.  Cheers, m

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure but you might try

```
docker run -i -t --volumes-from yourvolume ubuntu /bin/bash
```

You should then be able to access the directory, i think.

Comment: As long as you've still got "yourvolume" i believe launching any other container with --volumes-from should re-connect.

Comment: I still have the volume, but not the container that created it.  and the value of --volumes-from is the container name, which no longer exists...

Comment: Afraid i have little expertise, only just managed to grasp volumes myself. I'm not quite sure what you mean by you still have the volume. Posting your docker ps -a output may help someone else determine what you can do.

Comment: When you create, build and run a docker container with en external volume (data written to the host), you end up with an 'image', 'container' and 'volume'.    I have deleted the 'image' and 'container' but the 'volume' is still there.  The issue is, once the 'container' that linked to the 'volume' has gone, I cant see how to get back to the 'volume'

Answer (score 1):

When I came to this question, my main concern was data loss. Here is how **I copied data from a volume to AWS S3**:

```
# Create a dummy container - I like Python
host$ docker run -it -v my_volume:/datavolume1 python:3.7-slim bash

# Prepare AWS stuff
# executing 'cat ~/.aws/credentials' on your development machine
# will likely show them
python:3.7-slim$ pip install awscli
python:3.7-slim$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=yourkeyid
python:3.7-slim$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yoursecrectaccesskey

# Copy
python:3.7-slim$ aws s3 cp /datavolume1/thefile.zip s3://bucket/key/thefile.zip
```

Alternatively you can use [`aws s3 sync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html).

### MySQL / MariaDB

My specific example was about MySQL / MariaDB. If you want to backup a database of MySQL / MariaDB, just execute

```
$ mysqldump -u [username] -p [database_name] \
            --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false \
            > db1-backup-$(date +%F).sql
```

You might also want to consider

- `--skip-add-drop-table`: Skip the table creation if it already exists. Without this flag, the table is dropped.
- `--complete-insert`: Add the column names. Without this flag, there might be a column mismatch.

To restore the backup:

```
$ mysql -u [username] -p [database_name] < [filename].sql
```