# mongodb config file not found on dockerized mongodb

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker

First of all there, I know would be easier ways to solve my problem but in order to get a better understanding of docker, this is the way I want to solve running a dockerized mongodb.

I am right now trying to build my own mongodb docker image by taking a Dockerfile that's already there and modifying it. The modification: I want to be able to access a mongodb.conf file that the mongodb-server uses.

This is my Dockerfile. I only added one line `VOLUME ["/etc"]` and I changed the last line (I added the last `-f` parameter). Building the image and running it in a container worked fine without those changes.

```
FROM debian:jessie-slim
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y ca-certificates && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6 && \
gpg --export $GPG_KEYS > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mongodb.gpg
ARG MONGO_PACKAGE=mongodb-org
ARG MONGO_REPO=repo.mongodb.org
ENV MONGO_PACKAGE=${MONGO_PACKAGE} MONGO_REPO=${MONGO_REPO}
ENV MONGO_MAJOR 3.4
ENV MONGO_VERSION 3.4.18
RUN echo "deb http://$MONGO_REPO/apt/debian jessie/${MONGO_PACKAGE%-unstable}/$MONGO_MAJOR main" | tee "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/${MONGO_PACKAGE%-unstable}.list"
RUN echo "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/${MONGO_PACKAGE%-unstable}.list"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ${MONGO_PACKAGE}=$MONGO_VERSION
VOLUME ["/data/db"]
VOLUME ["/etc"]
WORKDIR /data
EXPOSE 27017
CMD ["mongod", "--smallfiles", "-f /etc/mongodb.conf"]
```

With my changes however, the builded image can not start. It immediately exits. `docker logs <container-name>` gives me

```
Error reading config file: No such file or directory
try 'mongod --help' for more information
```

I used the run command
`docker run -p 37017:27017 -d -v /tmp/mongodb/data:/data/db -v /tmp/mongodb/etc:/etc mongo-image` and expected that the file located at /tmp/mongodb/etc/mongodb.conf on my host-system would be found then (yes, it exists there, I placed it there).

What am I doing wrong? I am new to docker and I think I messed up the volumes maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify these lines:

```
VOLUME ["/data/db"]
VOLUME ["/etc"]
```

The `VOLUME` in your dockerfile creates separate directory on your host under `/var/lib/docker/volumes` For more info check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809646/what-is-the-purpose-of-volume-in-dockerfile).

`-v` option in your `docker run` command should be enough to mount mongodb.conf on your host inside the container.

**Update** I made a slight change in your dockerfile and it start working.
`CMD ["mongod", "--smallfiles", "-f", "/etc/mongodb.conf"]`

The `-f` and `/etc/mongodb.conf` should be separated by a comma, that is the syntax of `CMD`.

Please try this at your end and let me know.

Comment: Why was the VOLUME["/data/db"] then there? I read that it was for persistence. My Config should also be persistent. Can you explain a bit further please?

Comment: I updated my answer please check. And if it answers your question then please upvote and accept my answer. :)

Comment: Understood. But this does not explain why my config file is not found, does it?

Comment: In your case `VOLUME` has come into the picture and the data inside `/var/lib/docker/volumes` dir is the one getting mounted and since there is no mongodb.conf there hence you got `no such file or directory`

Comment: Why is `/var/lib/docker/volumes`the one getting mounted and not my specified `/tmp/mongodb/etc`? Because after starting I can see that a few files get generated there.

Comment: I guess I was wrong  your `-v` option is taking precedence and hence the files are getting generated. I updated my answer there is a syntax problem in your Dockerfile. Please check my answer again.

Comment: After your last update it worked! The syntax for CMD was wrong, it works now with the `-f` and `/etc/mongodb.conf` separated! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking for a quick guide on how to **install dockerized mongo** locally in 2019 and ending up with problems like that one mentioned in this question (which just happened to me 1 hour ago), I wrote a quick "guide": https://yosh.ke.mu/mongo_in_docker

Hope it would be useful for somebody.